# Navitel Navigator 5.0 map file

Tags: navigation

I have Navitel Navigator 5.0 map file(.nm3) for navigation.
Is ther is a way to open this file on PC?
Do we have a software that works as a navigator for PC such as Navital Navigation for android.

Comment: You had an [tag:arcgis-desktop] tag on this question but make no mention of that software in your question body (or title) so I have removed it.

Answer (score 1):

At [NaviTotal.com](http://www.navitotal.com/navitel-navigator-system-f133/navitel-navigator-377-for-wince-pna-t12503.html) I found:

> Navitel Navigator is multi-platform multilingual navigation, running
>   on Android, Symbian, Windows Mobile, iPhone, iPad, Bada, Java, Windows
>   CE platforms

which makes no mention of any PC flavours of Windows like 8, 7, Vista, etc so the answer to your second question would seem to be "No".